# Array Search not working - no idea why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am relatively new to python and currently working on a school project found online. When I run this code it should count how many times "Action" and "Sport" appear in the array.

```
forename = ["Joe", "George", "Oliver"]
HistoryGenre=[["Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport"], ["Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action"], ["Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport"]]
rr=1
ActionCounter=0
SportCounter=0
while rr==1:
    rec=input("Who would you like to recommend games for?")
    if rec in forename:
        rr+=1
        r=forename.index(rec)
        RepeatIndex=0
        for i in HistoryGenre[r]:
            if HistoryGenre[r:RepeatIndex]=="Action":
            ActionCounter+=1
            RepeatIndex+=1
            else:
                SportCounter+=1
                RepeatIndex+=1
            if RepeatIndex==9:
                print(ActionCounter)
                print(SportCounter)
```

When I run this code ActionCounter is printed as 0 and SportCounter is printed as 9. I don't understand how or why this is happening considering the outputs should be 7 and 3. It is more than likely a beginners mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue your code has is here

```
if HistoryGenre[r:RepeatIndex]=="Action":
```

To reference the nth item in HistoryGenre[r], do

```
HistoryGenre[r][n]
```

But you are in a for loop over HistoryGenre[r], so you can just do

```
for i in HistoryGenre[r]:
    if i == "Action":
        ...
```

I don't know if the project you were given forbade the count function, but it would make your life a lot easier. Instead of adding to the ActionCounter and SportCounter variables, you can find the count in each list like this:

```
ActionCounter = HistoryGenre[r][:9].count("Action")
```

The [:9] takes the first 9 elements in the list, which is all you appear to want. Also, you could use a dictionary, instead of two parallel lists. In a dictionary, elements have keys, so to refer to a certain element, you use its key. For example

```
 namebook = {"Joe":["Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport"], "George":["Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action"], "Oliver":["Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport"]}
```

To get Joe's book genres, just use

```
namebook["Joe"]
```

Using those changes, your program could be made a lot shorter.

```
namebook = {"Joe":["Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport"], "George":["Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action"], "Oliver":["Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport"]}
inputname = input()
print(namebook[inputname][:9].count("Action"))
print(namebook[inputname][:9].count("Sport"))
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much this has fixed my problem. It seems I was unaware of the proper syntax to search arrays. Yet I still have no idea why the output for ActionCounter was 0 and why it was 9 for SportCounter. Also, thank you for teaching me about dictionaries I have never used them.

Comment: @OliD HistoryGenre[r:RepeatIndex]=="Action" was never true, so it would always skip it and go to the else: SportsCounter+=1.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but since it has already been answered here is what I came up with to count the number of times `"Sports"` and `"Action"` occur in each sub list if you want to implement this.

```
for subList in HistoryGenre:

    string = ""

    string += ' '.join(subList) + " "

    words = {}

    for word in string.split():
        try:
            words[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            words[word] = 1

    print(words)


Out:
    {'Sport': 3, 'Action': 7}
    {'Sport': 7, 'Action': 3}
    {'Sport': 5, 'Action': 5}
```

`word` is the key

At first `words[word]` does not exist. So When I try `words[word] += 1`
the program is going to result in a `KeyError` because the key `word` does not exist.

So that the program does not crash I `except` the `KeyError`

Inside the `KeyError` block the key `word` is set to the value `1`.

so because the `word` is now a key every time the word is encountered in `string.split()`, `1` is added to the value of `word`

Comment: This would have really helped thank you for bettering my understanding. But what does the 'except KeyError: line do? I am quite unfamiliar with a lot of Python, evidently.